# Javascript: How to get new URL after using window.history.back()?

Tags: javascript, html, location, browser-history

I made the back button. With window.history.back() comes the previous url. but I can't reach this new url from the script section. When I print with console.log it still says old url. How can I access the url I just brought with history.back?

html:

```
  <i class="bi bi-arrow-left page-button" onClick="geri()"></i>
```

javascript:

```
 function geri(){
     window.history.back()
     let f = window.location.search.split("=")[1];
     console.log(f)//still the old link is coming. I want to see the new url that comes after the button is pressed
}
```

still the old link is coming. I want to see the new url that comes after the button is pressed

Comment: This method is asynchronous. Add a listener for the popstate event in order to determine when the navigation has completed.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/back

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ thanks. I found this before your answer. it worked. but this time my forward button is not working. When you go to the link, the forward button is reset. What can I do to make it not reset?